# Erro inflating class fragment utilizando maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

Quando eu executo meu app, após selecionar o evento que direciona para uma `activity` com uso de mapas, o mesmo finaliza com `Fatal Exception`.

> luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos.MapsActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML
>   file line #12: Error inflating class fragment

Estou utilizando a `API23` e realizei o update para suporte `SupportMapFragment`.

**activity_maps**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    também tentei com: android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos.MapsActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**build.gradle dependencies**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
```

**MapsActivity (apenas criei uma nova activity de mapas pelo próprio Android Studio)**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.i("InfoLocalizacao", Integer.toString(intent.getIntExtra("InfoLocalizacao", -1)));

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Comment: O layout que tem o mapa é esse que postou ou além do fragment tem mais views?

Comment: @ramaral o app possui dois layouts porém apenas esse que postei possui o mapa.

Comment: Troque o compile do gsm de: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'`  para: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`. E adicione seu arquivo de manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o *layout* contém apenas o mapa não necessita de o incluir em um *LinearLayout*.

O **activity_maps.xml** será a penas isto:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Se o mapa for para ser incluido num *layout* com outras views terá de remover as linhas com `xmlns:...`, elas já estão no *LinearLayout*:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro =[

Comment: Usou com ou sem *LinearLayout*?

Comment: Tentei das duas formas. Também pensei na possibilidade de utilizar o `getChildFragmentManager()` no comando `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);` mas deu não reconheceu o `getChildFragmentManager()`. Deve ser por causa do `extends FragmentActivity`

Comment: A única coisa que eu veja que pudesse estar mal era a questão das linhas `xmlns:`, de resto o código é uma cópia do que está em [Google Maps Android API - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)

Comment: Exatamente. De qualquer forma, obrigado!